# Missing inputs error on broadcast hex in litecoin testnet

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs, wallet, litecoin

I'm trying to create an LTC wallet in Node.js, but I keep getting the error 'Missing inputs' when I try to broadcast.

I'm trying to create a Litecoin wallet in Node.js using the 'litecoinjs' library. I can create the hex, but when I try to broadcast it on the 'https://tltc.bitaps.com/broadcast' site, it returns an error 'Missing inputs.' The UTXO I'm passing is as follows:

```
[
  {
    txid: '40b77ce9e96f0e85e4b026c1624c53b45a64c8a813df9a08ccde78c7a1b1d011',
    index: 1,
    amount: 95426081,
    script: 'a9141f652a42c312a2c4aee837672ce5c84a0b0455a087'
  }
]
```

And the code I'm using is this:

```
async function newTxExample(wallet, addressToSend, amount) {
    try {
        amount = await toLitoshi(amount);
        let utxo = await getUX(wallet.address);
        utxo = await converterUTXO(utxo);
        const transaction = await litecoinjs.newTransaction({
            network: 'testnet',
            wif: wallet.wif,
            utxo: utxo,
            output: [{
                address: addressToSend,
                amount: amount
            }],
            fee: 1000,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`ERROR: ${error}`);
    }
}
```